# ActiveX component error on Windows 2012

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to run a batch file using Task scheduler which runs vb scripts. When I run the script manually or from the
task scheduler on windows 7, then it works fine but 
when I try to run it manually or from a task scheduler on windows server 2012 R2 from some centralized server location, then I get the following error:
Microsoft VBScript Runtime error:ActiveX component can't create object:'Excel.Application'

This is my batch script code:

```
cscript %~dp0\CSV_To_Excel.vbs %1
```

This is my Excel code (converts CSV to Excel):

```
Dim Excel

file = "C:Folder1\Customer.csv"    
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt = fso.OpenTextFile(file).ReadAll

fso.OpenTextFile(file, 2).Write Replace(Replace(txt, "¬", vbTab), Chr(34), "")

'Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Calls the File System Object  

Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlNormal = -4143 

Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel.DisplayAlerts = False
With Excel
    .Workbooks.Open "C:Folder1\Customer.csv"
    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited, , , , True  'semicolon-delimited

    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs .ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Customer", xlNormal
        'Excel.Saved = True
        'Excel.Close
    .Quit
Excel.DisplayAlerts = True

   fso.DeleteFile("C:Folder1\Customer.csv") 'Deletes the file throught the DeleteFile function 
End With
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Office is installed on the server, you may need to register the activeX component. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-register-an-ActiveX-control-8fc743a1-e72b-4b55-af3a-85d326e53918